# How do I track down a Google Apps Script project from a Google Cloud project ID?

Tags: google-apps-script

How do I track down which Google Apps Script project "Project-id-19735......6273" actually is?

I've tried pasting it into the Cloud Console URL (https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?project=Project-id-19735......6273) but that doesn't bring anything up. I think this technique is working for projects I own, but not ones shared with me.

This is further to the email notifications we’ve been getting about [this updated OAuth on the GMail API](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914) and discussed further [here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+HariShankarDas/posts/hdq4bB4ewXm?cfem=1).

Answer (score 0):

Unless the owner of the GCP project explicitly grants your google account the appropriate permissions from the Cloud Console you won't be able to access the GCP project bound to an Apps Script project that's been shared with you.

The Apps Script project and GCP project are related but they are NOT one-and-the-same. The GCP project is more of a container and can actually reference multiple Apps Script projects. Each Apps Script project is basically a web app, with its own Client_ID and Client_Secret. That's why you can use `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()`; authentication and authorization are handled internally (the GAS editor handles oauth scopes based on usage context or what you define in the manifest JSON).

I'm guessing here, but I suspect that the owner of the GCP project would have to navigate to the [IAM (Identity & Access Management)](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam) page for the project and add you as a user with read/edit permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I do have edit access to the list of projects I've been sent, which is why Google sent them to me.